# aws-sdk ruby returns nil when deleting object

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Im trying to delete an object on S3 using the ruby aws-sdk (version 2). It works fine, but it returns this

```
<struct Aws::S3::Types::DeleteObjectOutput delete_marker=nil,version_id=nil, request_charged=nil>
```

Which doesnt make sense because in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#delete_object-instance_method) it says the response should be of the type:

> resp.delete_marker #=> true/false
>
> resp.version_id #=> String
>
> resp.request_charged #=> String, one of "requester"

Why am I becoming nil? I want to know if the object was deleted or not. I am getting that response both when i succeed in deleting the object and when I dont.

This is the code Im using to delete the object:

```
creds = Aws::Credentials.new(user_access_key,
                             user_secret_key,
                             session_token)

s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new( region: 'eu-west-1',
                          credentials: creds)


key = "myKey.csv"

r = s3.delete_object(bucket: "myBucket",
                     key: key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delete object was successful. The Amazon S3 API only returns those values under certain circumstances. In this case, your object was not in a versioned bucket (no version id or delete marker boolean), and is not configured for request-payer.

As a general rule, if the SDK does not raise an error from the response, it is successful. In this case, the API reference documentation may be confusing as it does not clearly indicate that these values may be `nil`.

[aws-sdk-ruby Aws::CloudFormation::Client#delete_stack Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CloudFormation/Client.html#delete_stack-instance_method)

Comment: Ok thanks, the documentation was indeed confusing. Hope they change it :)

Comment: I receive the same response from Amazon S3 with nil values and my object IS NOT removed

Comment: @yaru this response doesn't necessarily mean that your object has been removed. One of the major reasons for this in my experience is the url in your post request. Make sure the `/` haven't been replaced by `%2F` while getting the key from amazon

Comment: I'm not sure why this is down voted as it is correct. aws-sdk-ruby returns an empty, or nil response when deleting stacks. Doesn't necessarily mean it did the right one or checks if hte stack exists before hand. That's kind of up to the developer to do those kinds of sanity checks.